# Subview of TableView removed - Tableview not visible

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, core-plot

For the first time working with CorePlot (after a couple of hours trying to set it up :P )

on my view, i have a tableview. when a certain IBAction is called i want to show another view (a graph) instead of the tableview.

my approach was to add a subview with the same size to the tableview. it works fine to display the graph, but when i remove the graphs view from [table subviews] the tableview does not reappear.

note:

```
expenseTable: my tableView
hasSubView: (BOOL) that indicates if a graph is shown right now or not
```

code

```
-(IBAction)displayDayBalanceGraph:(id)sender{
if (hasSubView) {

    [[expenseTable subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    NSLog(@"%@",expenseTable.subviews);
}

else{
    [self initializeMonthArray];
    CPTGraphHostingView *host = [self buildGraphView];
    [expenseTable addSubview:host];
    CPTXYGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc ]initWithFrame:host.frame];
    host.hostedGraph = graph;
    CPTScatterPlot *plot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc]init ];
    plot.dataSource = self;
    [graph addPlot:plot];
    [expenseTable reloadData];   
    hasSubView = !hasSubView;
}
}

-(CPTGraphHostingView *)buildGraphView{
    CPTGraphHostingView *view = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 312, 260)];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[self grayColor]];
    return view;
}
```

1st Screenshot: **TableView displayed**

[image: tableview]

2nd Screenshot: **GraphView displayed**
sidenote: this is a sampleplot =)

[image: graph]

3rd Screenshot: **GraphView dismissed**

[image: empty]

has anyone an idea what i missed? (or messed ;) )

Comment: - since all cells are subviews i must be removing them all i just figured. so i would need to know what index the new subview has? any ideas?

Comment: How are you dismissing the GraphView?

Comment: see code above: `[[expenseTable subviews]makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not generally a good idea to add views as subviews of `UITableView`.

Instead, you could either remove the table view and replace it with the Core Plot view:

```
[tableView removeFromSuperview];
[containerView addSubview:corePlotView];
```

Make sure you have a reference to the table view somewhere or it will be released.

Comment: i'll give that a try later today thanks in advance (of course ill ccept if it works). i was a bit suspocious about using subvies on the table but i thought ill try the (for me) most obvious way frst - i didnt know that you could replace views :-)

Comment: just tried it - actually [tableview superview] does not have a member function `replaceSubview` - any ideas? 
the tableview is within a uiviewcontroller that just implements the <UITableViewDelegate> and datasource.

Comment: Sorry, I was answering for Mac OS. On iOS that method doesn't exist, I've updated my answer. Just so you're aware, iOS questions should be tagged [tag:cocoa-touch] rather than [tag:cocoa]. I've updated the tag.

Comment: as  you said in your comment cocoa  touch does not contain 'replacesubvie' for views so it does not work sadly

Comment: I also said that I updated my answer. All you do is remove the table view, then add the Core Plot view.

Comment: sorry that i took so long to accept your answer =) but thanks again. works smoothly now =)